# Take the Last Requested Async Result and Cancelling Previous Unfinished Tasks

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have multiple heavy job calculation requests. The job may take different time. By using `async` and  `await` I want to take the last requested result with canceling eventually unfinished previous tasks.

Currently I'm using BackGroundWorker with setting a job ID. I used only the the result with the last requested ID.

Can I rewrite the code with using `async` `await`?

```
private int backtestId;

private void PrepareStrategyCalculation()
{
    backtestId = backtestManager.GetNextBacktestId();
    strategy.BacktestId = backtestId;
    backtestManager.StartBacktestWorker(strategy.Clone());
}

private void BacktestManager_StrategyBacktested(object sender, StrategyBacktestEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.BacktestObject.Strategy.BacktestId != backtestId) return;

    var calculatedStrategy = e.BacktestObject.Strategy;
    ...
}
```

EDIT:

Is this a solution?

```
private int backtestId;

private async void PrepareStrategyCalculation()
{
    backtestId = backtestManager.GetNextBacktestId();
    strategy.BacktestId = backtestId;
    var calculatedStrategy = await backtestManager.StartBacktestAsync(strategy.Clone());
    if (calculatedStrategy.BacktestId != backtestId) return;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how you are calling multiple requests? (There only appears to be one request in your code.) And is the condition to stop when you get the first value back where `calculatedStrategy.BacktestId != backtestId`?

Comment: There are many reasons to call `PrepareStrategyCalculation()`: a value changed by a user, data file load, settings changed... Unfortunately, there is no cancellation to older requests that are still running. They are left to the destiny. The main goal is the result to correspond to the last settings by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your code is CPU-bound, then `Task.Run` is a suitable substitute for `BackgroundWorker`.

You can use `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel tasks. So, something like this would work, assuming that `StartBacktestAsync` is called from a single-threaded context such as a UI thread:

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
async Task StartBacktestAsync()
{
  if (_cts != null)
    _cts.Cancel();
  _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  try
  {
    var token = _cts.Token;
    await Task.Run(() => Backtest(token));
  }
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
  {
    // Any special logic for a canceled operation.
  }
}

void Backtest(CancellationToken token)
{
  ... // periodically call token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
```

Comment: It's a very good solution. So I just have to send Cancellation to all previously started tasks, which leaves the last requested only.

Comment: I think this code doesn't guarantee that the result is from the last call. See here my implementation: https://gist.github.com/PopovMP/9e1970e31436b6b0fe86  (SO really sucks when have to answer to answer):

Comment: @MiroslavPopov: There was a race condition in copying the `CancellationToken`. https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/41667b966731e94ad49d/revisions